# Creating a space in the cout line for c++

Tags: c++, space

I am very new to coding. I was wondering how I can create a space in this out print using vim. I wrote a code for a guessing number game. The count is the variable. Count is the number tries it took the user to guess the correct number.

This is the code that I wrote to show that response:

```
cout << "You guessed it in" << count <<"tries"<<endl;
```

The out print does not put a space between "You guessed it in" and "tries"

It comes out like this for example.

> You guessed in in4tries

How do I create a space so it is easier for the user to read?

Comment: Just like you created the other 3 spaces in your output...

Comment: Also, this is completely independent of the choice of text editor, please think before you tag.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the space here

```
cout << "You guessed it in " << count <<" tries"
                          ^              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using #define like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _ << " " <<
#define print cout <<
#define el << endl;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int y = 1;
    int y2 = 2;
    int y3 = 3;
    print y _ y2 _ y3 el
    return 0;
}
```